# How to display result of a row in column in Tableau desktop

Tags: tableau-api, level-of-detail

I have a  table  :

| id | field_name | control_number | typologie | NB1 | NB2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SUSY | FIELDX1 | RG-FI-03 | P | 00 | 36 |
| SUSY | FIELDX1 | RG-FI-04 | N | 12 | 46 |

I want to create a column  to display  the result of  NB1 when typologie is equal  to "N" in order to have :

| id | field_name | control_number | typologie | NB1 | NB2 | NBIF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SUSY | FIELDX1 | RG-FI-03 | P | 00 | 36 | 12 |
| SUSY | FIELDX1 | RG-FI-04 | N | 12 | 46 | 12 |

Answer (score 0):

Not that difficult as it seems..

Assuming that you have to replicate this typology for each `id` as a group.. create a calculated field `NBIF` with the following calculation

```
{Fixed [Id] : min(
IF [Typologie] = "N" THEN [NB1] END
)}
```

If however, your group/level of detail is `field_name` replace `[Id]` with `[field_number]` in the above formula and your field is ready

[image]